# JS or jQuery. Show a different nav when i click on button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'I have two navbar but one is hiden.

My goal is to show a navbar when the user clicks on the button `navbar1` and show an other navbar when the user clicks on the second button.

How can I do it ?

I have different subnav between both nav.

My code :

```js
function showDivNav1() {
   document.getElementById('Nav1').style.display = "block";
   document.getElementById('ShowNav1').disabled = true;
   document.getElementById('ShowNav2').disabled = false;
}
   
function showDivNav2() {
   document.getElementById('Nav2').style.display = "block";
   document.getElementById('ShowNav1').disabled = true;
   document.getElementById('ShowNav2').disabled = false;
}
```

```css
body {margin:0;}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
    background-color: #111;
}

.active {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav1">
    <ul>
        <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
        <li style="float:right"><a id="ShowNav1" type="button" onclick="ShowDivNav1()">Nav1</a></li>
        <li style="float:right"><a id="ShowNav2" type="button" onclick="ShowDivNav1()">Nav2</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="nav2">
    <ul>
        <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
        <li style="float:right"><a id="ShowNav1" type="button" onclick="ShowDivNav2()">Nav1</a></li>
        <li style="float:right"><a id="ShowNav2" type="button" onclick="ShowDivNav2()">Nav2</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div style="padding:20px;margin-top:30px;background-color:white;height:1500px;">
    <h1>Barre de navigation accrocher au haut de la page</h1>
    <h2>Defiler la page pour voir l'effet</h2>
    <h2>La navigation restera en haut de la page</h2>

    <p>Un petit de peu de texte, un petit peu de texte</p>
    <p>Un petit de peu de texte, un petit peu de texte</p>
    <p>Un petit de peu de texte, un petit peu de texte</p>
    <p>Un petit de peu de texte, un petit peu de texte</p>
    <p>Un petit de peu de texte, un petit peu de texte</p>
    <p>Un petit de peu de texte, un petit peu de texte</p>
    <p>Un petit de peu de texte, un petit peu de texte</p>
    <p>Un petit de peu de texte, un petit peu de texte</p>
    <p>Un petit de peu de texte, un petit peu de texte</p>
    <p>Un petit de peu de texte, un petit peu de texte</p>
    <p>Un petit de peu de texte, un petit peu de texte</p>
    <p>Un petit de peu de texte, un petit peu de texte</p>

</div>
```

Comment: Did you check for console errors?

Comment: Hint : js is case sensitive

Comment: console errors ?

Comment: You don't open developper console when coding in javascript?

Comment: Nope :/ should i ?

Comment: Just click F12 on the keyboard

Comment: How can you know errors then?

Comment: just change this js showDivNav1() to ShowDivNav1()

Comment: Wrong HTML with same id on multiple elements

Comment: many small mistakes

Comment: It's simple your function's has showDivNav1 here 's' is in small letter, and you have used Capital 's' in onclick function. Javascript is case sensitive. Take care of it, Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

Many mistakes `Nav1` needs to be `nav1`

`ShowDivNav2` need to be `showDivNav2` ...

```js
function showDivNav1() {
   document.getElementById('nav1').style.display = "block";
   document.getElementById('ShowNav1').disabled = true;
   document.getElementById('ShowNav2').disabled = false;
   }
    function showDivNav2() {
   document.getElementById('nav2').style.display = "block";
   document.getElementById('ShowNav1').disabled = true;
   document.getElementById('ShowNav2').disabled = false;
   }
```

```css
 body {margin:0;}

     ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    }

    li {
    float: left;
    }

    li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    }

    li a:hover:not(.active) {
    background-color: #111;
    }

     .active {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    }
```

```html
<div id="nav1">
    <ul>
    <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
     <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
    <li style="float:right"><a id="ShowNav1" type="button" 
    onclick="showDivNav1()">Nav1</a></li>
     <li style="float:right"><a id="ShowNav2" type="button" 
    onclick="showDivNav2()">Nav2</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
     <div id="nav2">
     <ul>
    <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
     <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
    <li style="float:right"><a id="ShowNav1" type="button" 
    onclick="showDivNav1()">Nav1</a></li>
    <li style="float:right"><a id="ShowNav2" type="button" 
    onclick="showDivNav2()">Nav2</a></li>
    </ul>
     </div>

    <div style="padding:20px;margin-top:30px;background- 
    color:white;height:1500px;">
    <h1>Barre de navigation accrocher au haut de la page</h1>
    <h2>Defiler la page pour voir l'effet</h2>
    <h2>La navigation restera en haut de la page</h2>

    <p>Un petit de peu de texte, un petit peu de texte</p>
    <p>Un petit de peu de texte, un petit peu de texte</p>
     <p>Un petit de peu de texte, un petit peu de texte</p>
     <p>Un petit de peu de texte, un petit peu de texte</p>
     <p>Un petit de peu de texte, un petit peu de texte</p>
     <p>Un petit de peu de texte, un petit peu de texte</p>
      <p>Un petit de peu de texte, un petit peu de texte</p>
     <p>Un petit de peu de texte, un petit peu de texte</p>
     <p>Un petit de peu de texte, un petit peu de texte</p>
     <p>Un petit de peu de texte, un petit peu de texte</p>
     <p>Un petit de peu de texte, un petit peu de texte</p>
     <p>Un petit de peu de texte, un petit peu de texte</p>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got a working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zxja8fwt/21/) with **JQuery** for you here you just need to add the disable.

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#nav2').hide();
});

$('#ShowNav2-1').click(function(){
    $('#nav2').hide();
    $('#nav1').show();
});
$('#ShowNav1-2').click(function(){
    $('#nav1').hide();
    $('#nav2').show();
});
```

Here is your code with the pure **Javascript** solution.

```js
  document.getElementById('nav2').style.display = "none";


function ShowDivNav1() {
   document.getElementById('nav2').style.display = "none";
   document.getElementById('nav1').style.display = "block"; 
   document.getElementById('ShowNav1').disabled = true;
   document.getElementById('ShowNav2').disabled = false;
}
   
function ShowDivNav2() {
   document.getElementById('nav1').style.display = "none";
   document.getElementById('nav2').style.display = "block";
   document.getElementById('ShowNav1').disabled = true;
   document.getElementById('ShowNav2').disabled = false;
}
```

```css
body {margin:0;}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
    background-color: #111;
}

.active {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav1">
    <ul>
        <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#news">News1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">About1</a></li>
        <li style="float:right"><a id="ShowNav1" type="button" onclick="ShowDivNav1()">Nav1</a></li>
        <li style="float:right"><a id="ShowNav2" type="button" onclick="ShowDivNav2()">Nav2</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="nav2">
    <ul>
        <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#news">News2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">About2</a></li>
        <li style="float:right"><a id="ShowNav1" type="button" onclick="ShowDivNav1()">Nav1</a></li>
        <li style="float:right"><a id="ShowNav2" type="button" onclick="ShowDivNav2()">Nav2</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div style="padding:20px;margin-top:30px;background-color:white;height:1500px;">
    <h1>Barre de navigation accrocher au haut de la page</h1>
    <h2>Defiler la page pour voir l'effet</h2>
    <h2>La navigation restera en haut de la page</h2>

    <p>Un petit de peu de texte, un petit peu de texte</p>
    <p>Un petit de peu de texte, un petit peu de texte</p>
    <p>Un petit de peu de texte, un petit peu de texte</p>
    <p>Un petit de peu de texte, un petit peu de texte</p>
    <p>Un petit de peu de texte, un petit peu de texte</p>
    <p>Un petit de peu de texte, un petit peu de texte</p>
    <p>Un petit de peu de texte, un petit peu de texte</p>
    <p>Un petit de peu de texte, un petit peu de texte</p>
    <p>Un petit de peu de texte, un petit peu de texte</p>
    <p>Un petit de peu de texte, un petit peu de texte</p>
    <p>Un petit de peu de texte, un petit peu de texte</p>
    <p>Un petit de peu de texte, un petit peu de texte</p>

</div>
```